# Breaking out of setTimeout loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having some trouble breaking out of a setTimeout loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
  setTimeout(function (i) {
    return function () {
      console.log("turn no. " + i);
      if (table.game.playerWon) {
        console.log('Player won');
        // I want to stop the loop now
        // i = 75; didn't work
      }
    };
  }(i), 100 * i);
}
```

I've read like 100 `setTimeout` related posts, but can't figure this one out.

edit:

Let me clarify a bit when I'm trying to accomplish.

My game has 75 turns, each turn should take about 500ms, during that turn I want to check if a condition is met and announce that the player won, after the player has won there is no need to continue the rest of the turns.

Comment: You know you set 75 parallel timeouts ?

Comment: assign setTimeout to a variable, then clearTimeout(that variable)

Comment: I honestly have no idea what I'm doing in the above code. I've edited my post to clarify a bit what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You are mis-understanding asynchronysity. The loop has already completed before even one of your `setTimeout` calls has run.  So you have scheduled 75 events in one go and then they will start firing.

Comment: I hope you aware of the difference between `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

Comment: setInterval executes every x amount of time and setTimeout waits x amount of time if I'm right.

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of setting all those timers, create one continuous timer with `setInterval`:

```
var counter = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function () {

    console.log("turn no. " + counter);

    if (table.game.playerWon) {
        console.log('Player won');
    }

    if (counter >= 75 || table.game.playerWon) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    counter++;

}, 100);
```

If your turns should take 500ms, change that last `100` to `500`.

Comment: This answer worked instantly. Thanks alot. Amazed by Stackoverflow's answering speed!
Gonna accept this one as an answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 13):

#### You shouldn't use a for loop , just a recursive setTimeout

- Read about [the recursive setTimeout pattern](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/a-recursive-settimeout-pattern)
- When saying `about 500ms`, I assume it doesn't have to be so accurate
- [setInterval is harmful](http://zetafleet.com/blog/why-i-consider-setinterval-harmful) and most developers are probably not aware of it.

#### `setInterval` does not fit for so many things:

- If an error occurs you cannot stop the train.
- If you need different execution time steps.
- If you need to pass data inside the chain.
- If you need to do something asynchronous.
- And the worse thing - **SETINTERVAL DOES NOT GUARANTEE EXECUTION**
- So use it only if you know what you are doing!

#### Solution:

```
var func = function(i){

    return function(){
        if (i >= 75) return;
        console.log("turn no. " + i);

        if(table.game.playerWon) {
            console.log('Player won');
        } else {
            setTimeout(func(++i), 500); 
        }

    }   
}

setTimeout(func(0), 500);
```

#### You can run it in `node.js` if you want to check how it works:

```
var winTurn = 10;

var func = function(i){

    return function(){
        if (i >= 75) return;
        console.log("turn no. " + i);

        if(i === winTurn) {
            console.log('Player won');
        } else {
            setTimeout(func(++i), 50); 
        }

    }   
}

setTimeout(func(1), 50);
```

Comment: I see no recursion here. A recurrence, maybe. Also, this technique tends to add a drift to the clock, which seems indesirable in that particular case.

Comment: Very dogmatic tone in this latter blog article. Looks more like the guy writing this feels uneasy with asynchronous execution and is fixated on Ajax calls (which do not require any timeout, by the way). IMHO you are better off knowing what you're doing before trying to tackle asynchronous execution, be it with periodic or single-shot timers.

Comment: dogmatic or not, You cannot ignore these problems. Also, in node.js every little thing is asynchronous (not just AJAX) and might has too much latency.

Comment: *you cannot stop the train* Lol) and upvote. Helped me with an idea to my issue and also is informative.

Answer (score 5):

I think would be better you use a setInterval instead of setTimeout.

And for clear both of them you assign them to a variable and then you clear the timeout with

```
var myVar = setTimeout(func, time);
var myVar2 = setInterval(func, time);

clearTimeout(myVar);
clearInterval(myVar2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you should write

```
var timeouts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 75; i++) {

    timeouts[i] = setTimeout(function(i) {

        return function() {

            console.log("turn no. " + i);

            if(table.game.playerWon) {
                console.log('Player won');
                // I want to stop the loop now
                for(var k = i; k < timeouts.length; k++) {
                    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
                }
            }

        };

    }(i), 100*i);

}
```

Another simpler workaround is a call only `setTimeout` when `table.game.playerWon` is false.

```
var timeoutFunction = function(i) {

    return function() {

        console.log("turn no. " + i);

        if(table.game.playerWon) {
            console.log('Player won');
            // Game stopped
        } else {
            timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction(i+1), 100);  
        }
    };

}

var timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction(0), 100);
```

Hope it helps