# how to stop loop while using setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'date'];
let found = 0;

fruits.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (found == 0) {
    console.log("value", value)

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (value.length > 1) {
        found = 1;
      }
    }, 200)
  }
})
```

Stop loop when it get caught found=1 but after using `setTimout` it does not behave like this how to solve it

Comment: you can't stop `forEach` method, you can use `for loop` instead

Comment: Why do you need a timeout inside the loop. The loop will long be finished before the first timeout ever occurs. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking out of setTimeout loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240865/breaking-out-of-settimeout-loop)

Comment: Can you explain the context? Why do you need the `setTimeout`?

Comment: What is the actual result you are looking for. I think this is an X/Y problem. tell us what you want to see and we can help

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'date'];
let found = 0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < fruits.length ; i++ ) {
  const value = fruits[i];
  if (value.length > 1) {
     found = 1;
     console.log("Founded", value)
     break;
   } else {
     console.log("Value", value)
   }
}
console.log("Found: ",found)
```